# When to Cast a Close Vote

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closing

I'm having trouble expressing myself clearly about this issue, so please ask me to elaborate (or perhaps someone has better words than I).

---

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203751/what-is-the-most-effective-way-of-teaching-mathematics-to-my-7-year-old-kid) about how to effectively teach mathematics to a child is a good example of a question for which I am conflicted about casting a close vote. I think the best way to phrase my question is as follows:

> Are close votes used to *enforce* a prescribed notion of what questions are to be featured on the site, or are they intended to naturally *create* the environment desired by the users?

Certainly, this question is not constructive in the strict sense that it will not admit a definitive answer. Still, I feel the question is a good faith effort by a new user and could easily be reworded as a "reference request" about teaching children. My dilemma is this: Do I cast a vote to close because I don't believe it is the kind of question normally welcomed by the community, or should I leave it be and wait for five users who have a stronger *personal* feeling that the question does not belong? Of course, five such users might not exist, and then the question remains open. Is this the desired outcome?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that it is a bad idea to closevote based on what you think that other people want (or have close-voted in the past).

If there aren't five people that actually don't want a particular question that is a splendid reason to leave it open. I don't even see a problem here.

Answer (score 2):

**The following is mostly my own personal opinion.**

In the faq it says that:

> avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite **__**?”
>
> your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I  use **_** for **_**, what do you use?”
>
> there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

(I don't know how to format a list in the quotes...)

In my opinion this question comes close to these types of questions. Especially because the OP in that question asks: "*What is your preferred way?*".

However, I could imagine someone actually saying some objective about the question. I don't know a lot about math-pedagogy, but one could imagine that there actually has been done some research into how to teach math to a $7$-year old: memorization versus playing math games with pictures.